# Gradle sync issue in Android Studio 3.2.1

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have updated my Android studio to 3.2.1 since then am getting error as below

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could
>   not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0.

hence unable to build my application

I have unchecked offline too

my dependencies in gradle file

```
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

kindly suggest a solution for this

Regards.
Nagendra

Comment: i have open network internet access

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using old version of build tool in project level build.gradle.

Try

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your [Android Gradle plugin](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin)

1- Upade the `classpath` in top-level `build.gradle` to:

```
buildscript {
    ....
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}
```

2- Update the Gradle version to 4.6 in the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file by changing the `distributionUrl` to:

```
...
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
...
```

3- Go to ReBuild Project

Answer (score 0):

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

add this to the dependencies of buildscript. then Sync the project.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response,

Isuue was with proxy blocking the downloads,i have commented the proxy in gradle.properties then its started working, i was trying in the office network.

Regards.
Nagendra